# How can I start up a ruby server script when I start up my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'd like for a ruby server script that lives in my rails app root folder to accept connections from clients (the clients are not browsers--not that this really matters i guess) and update the db of my rails app while my rails app is running. Therefore, I'd like for it to be told somehow to start running whenever my web server starts serving up my rails app and stop running whenever my web server stops serving my rails app. How can I do this? Is this as simple as putting the name/path of my ruby server script somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into [Foreman](http://michaelvanrooijen.com/articles/2011/06/08-managing-and-monitoring-your-ruby-application-with-foreman-and-upstart/), a gem specifically for launching multiple processes in your server environment.

Comment: Thanks! Finally looked into Foreman and it's great and so easy to set up!